# How to connect DB2 from R?

Tags: r, db2, connection

We have installed Data Studio 4.1.0.0 Client to access the data that is stored in DB2. We have installed DB2 11.1 64bit on our PC which has a Windows 7 64 bit.

I need to connect to the DB2 data from 64bit R.

We tried the following

```
library (RODBC)

driver.name <- "{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}"
db.name <- "SBXSHRD"
host.name <- "XX.XXX.X.XX"
port <- "60012"
user.name <- "X20XX4"
pwd <- "SXXXXX01"

#Connection String
con.text <- paste ("DRIVER =", driver.name,
                   "; Database =", db.name,
                   "; Hostname =", host.name,
                   "; Port =", port,
                   "; PROTOCOL = TCPIP",
                   "; UID =", user.name,
                   "; PWD =", pwd, sep = "")

#Connect to DB2
con1 <- odbcDriverConnect (con.text)

top <- sqlQuery (con1,
               "SELECT *
               FROM ODS_CANALES_LINK.VW_OP_D_TRANSACCIONCANAL
               where CODMES_PROC = 201708
               FETCH FIRST 3 ROW ONLY
               ",
               errors = FALSE)
```

But I get the following result in r

```
> con1 <- odbcDriverConnect(con.text)
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con.text) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM004, code 0, message [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] Error de SQLAllocHandle del controlador en SQL_HANDLE_ENV
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con.text) : ODBC connection failed
```

here a detail of the DB2 that we have and a snapshot of what we are doing in R

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kFax.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP3Br.jpg)

Comment: The DB2 service level (10.5.0.8) in your image does not match the DB2 version you claim to use (11.1).

Comment: Did you try the suggestions at the IBM page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21229860

Answer (score 0):

RJDBC works quite well. But ... On one occasion, after the complete rebuild of docker image, I got all resultsets with changed column names because they changed name from jdbc function getColumnName to getColumnLabel.

https://github.com/s-/RJDBC/commit/7f1c1eec25ed90ec5ed71141189b816e2a3c2657

```
library(RJDBC)
CONSTR <- "jdbc:db2://hostname:446/database"
jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", "db2jcc4.jar")

connect <- function() {
   dbConnect(jcc, CONSTR, user="scott", password="tiger")
}

dept <- function() {
  con <-  connect()
  sql <- "SELECT DEPTNO, DEPTNAME FROM DSN8710.dept"      
  rs <- dbSendQuery(con, sql)
  x <- dbFetch(rs)
  dbClearResult(rs)
  # change column names, because the names are not stable!
  names(x) <- c('DEPTNO', 'DEPTNAME')
  dbDisconnect(con)
  x
}
```